# Gênero feminino da palavra - Responsivo

Tags: sinônimos, gênero, neologismos

Quando escrevo a palavra - `Responsivo` em algum campo de texto utilizando o navegador Google Chrome nenhum erro é detetado no dicionário do Chrome, mas já quando tento escrevê-la no feminino - `Responsiva` ele sublinha-a como erro de escrita.

[image]

O que me levou à pergunta:
Será que existe um gênero feminino para esta palavra, ou será mesmo este o feminino para esta palavra?

<sub>Adicionalmente, alguém sabe um sinónimo para isto que tenha uma versão feminina da palavra?</sub>

Comment: Em pt_PT reponsivo nem sequer existe.

Comment: Existe algum sinónimo para descrever o mesmo em pt_PT @JorgeB. ?

Comment: afinal estou enganado, existe sim, mas não se usa.

Comment: @JorgeB. Também pensei que não existia.

Comment: Atenção que o dicionário do Chrome não é assim tão abrangente. Poderá escapar-lhe uma palavra ou outra.

Comment: Realmente o @E_net4 tem razão aqui não me dá erro nenhum.

Comment: É estranho então estar ali a aparecer-me isso. E tenho o idioma configurado para pt_PT

Comment: @Chun os dicionários dos browsers não são confiáveis, escrever "ativo" dá erro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Responsivo](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/responsivo) é um adjetivo biforme terminado em `o`.
Segundo a regra para esse ajetivo, na forma feminina troca-se o `o` por `a`.
Por ser adjetivo, a concordância deve acompanhar o substantivo mais próximo.

`Responsivo` é mais comum por estar mais presente acompanhando substantivos masculinos:

"O site responsivo [..]"
"O *layout* responsivo [..]"
"O *design* responsivo [..]"

Mas pode ser usado terminando em "a":

"[..] carta responsiva [..]"
"[..] tela responsiva [..]"

O dicionário do Chrome não é altamente confiável. Ele já me informou de erros gramaticais triviais inexistentes.

Comment: O corretor de ortografia de Google é desenvolvido não com regras com a maioria dos corretores, mas com *big data*.  Assim tenta poder incluir novas palabras e marcas, etc, e também ter em conta a gramática simples, sem interação humana como os outros, só com heurísticas.  O problema é que às vezes uma ou outra palavra não aparece muito no corpus, ou pela forma de intuir a gramaticalidade duma palavra, o corretor acha-a incorreta (por concordancia, categoria gramatical, terminologia, etc).